# What is a DF manuscript?

Tags: scientific-publishing, science

I apologize if this is obvious, but what is a D.F. manuscript? See [this link](https://books.google.com/books?id=2kgQsaltRO4C&pg=PA374&lpg=PA374&dq=%22df%20manuscript%22&source=bl&ots=c4w3V7GkkM&sig=5P2DhJBmkc64Hq0f-gDkDquPEMg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYop2ehOrXAhUOleAKHcSRC-UQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22df%20manuscript%22&f=false) for an example of the term's use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a transparent error, and therefore unlikely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

D.F. are the initials of one of the authors (Steiner). ;-)